# how to sort data in plist?

Tags: iphone

is it possible to sort data inserted in plist in alphabetical order? and how? if not how to dot it using arrays or any other method?

thanks in advace

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Make sure you read the FAQ before posting questions. Also, before posting questions, try to find the answer using the search-function. There are many questions and solving answers posted already on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

```
// read the file into a dictionary
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourfile" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
// sort it
NSArray *sortedArray = [[myDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
// iterate and print results
for(NSString *key in sortedArray) {
    NSLog(@"key=%@,value=%@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
}
```